# Single port register file

Tags: memory-hardware

I have a test that asks to build a register file using only a single port.
The register file should also output 2 values, the read values, and be able to write one.

I tried to build it, but ,simply put, I think this is impossible, isn't it?

I also have another task , in the very same test, asking me to do the same exact thing but using 2 ports this time. Even this one seems impossible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Programming is off-topic here. Help with tests might be off-topic on all sites in the network.

Comment: It's not a test I have to submit, It's just a test of last year I'm trying to solve in order to practice. 
And this is not programming, it's an hardware question, about register files...

Comment: Hardware questions are also off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry  then, I must have misunderstood the purpose of the forum. My bad.

Comment: Given the question is tagged memory-hardware: What ore the components `to build a register file`? What does `using [a] single port` mean, what `the register file should also output 2 values`?

Comment: I have to build it using logical ports (and,or,not). Normally I would build it with 3 ports, 2 of which would be for reading and 1 for writing. The ports  contain the address of the register to read or to write.  The registers are selected with a decoder, and are made using flip-flops, which of course are activated by an external clock signal. Moreover, the register file has a data input, which has to be written in the register given in the write port.  As an output,  it yields the content of the registers specified in the read ports. I have to do all of this, using only a single port.

Comment: A port is considered to be the input that carries the address of a register in the register file.

Comment: nvm i solved it.